# Subsection float barriers with figures/Tables

Tags: tables, spacing, sectioning, formatting

I've been having lots of issues lately trying to keep tables and figures stay within the sections and the order I want them in. I have 2 tables formatted in 2 separate sub-sub-sections. I try separating them but the space is enormously huge when I use a \FloatBarrier. please help lol.

```
\documentclass[12 point, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[hdivide={1in,*,1in}, vdivide={1in,*,1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, longtable, acronym, verbatim, subfigure, tikz, listings, color, float}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,breaklines=true,frame=L,xleftmargin=\parindent,language=C,showstringspaces=false,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},identifierstyle=\color{blue},stringstyle=\color{orange},}\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,frame=L,xleftmargin=\parindent,language=[x86masm]Assembler,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
}\lstset{ basicstyle=\scriptsize,numbers=left,numberstyle=\footnotesize,stepnumber=1,numbersep=10pt,backgroundcolor=\color{white},frame=single,captionpos=b,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=false
}


\begin{document}
\author{ Daniel Webb\\
  Electrical Engineering-UNL}
\date{02//2020}
\title{ECEN 347 Lab 2\\
       Date: 3/01/2021 }
\maketitle
\pagebreak
\section{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Experiment}
\subsection{Transistor Operation Design (Transistor Bias)}
 Design a bias circuit in Fig. for operation in (cutoff, triode, saturation) and note which one has lowest power consumption given $R_1$ =100 ohms, $R_2=1000 ohms$
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{MOSFET CIRCUIT.PNG}
    \caption{Mosfet Circuit }
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
1) Place the LED in series with R, $V_{DD}$= 5 V while varying $V_{GS}$ from 0 V to 5 V. Record when the LED starts turning on; this will determine when the transistor is in the on state for overcoming Gate Source voltage required. \\
2) Remove the LED and increase $V_{GS}$ observed by 1 V. Step up $V_{DD}$ from 0V : 8V in 1V increments. Measure $I_{DS}$ and $V_{DS}$ for each step value and calculate $R_{DS}$ from these values and Power found by P = power dissipated from transistor ($P_{R_{DS}}$) + drain connected resistor ($P_R$)


\subsection{Transistor Inverter, Switching operation}
\subsection{Propogation Delay of Transistor Inverter}
\subsection{Logic Gates}


\section{Results}
\subsection{Transistor Operation Design (Transistor Bias)}
%Summarize the component selection R and operation set up (VGS,VGS(th),VDD,and P) of your design. For each resistor, include VGS(th),VGS and one table with the values of ID,VDS,RDS, P , and PR and for RDS each value of VDD(Numeral 2).


%Operation setup ($V_{GS}$,$V_{GS}$(th),$V_{DD}$,and P) of design }
\subsubsection{Part2: 100 ohm R}

1)$V_{GS}=$ that turns on LED //

2)Adjusted $V_{GS}= $ //


\begin{table}[]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
     $V_{GS(th)}$& $V_{GS}$ & $V_{DD}$ & $I_{DS}$ & $V_{DS}$ & $R_{DS}$ & P & $P_R$ \\
     \hline\hline
     0 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
     1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
     2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{100 ohm R selection }
\label{tab: table name}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
\subsubsection{Part2: 1000 Ohm R}
1)$V_{GS}=$ that turns on LED //

2)Adjusted $V_{GS}= $ //
\begin{table}[]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
     $V_{GS(th)}$& $V_{GS}$ & $V_{DD}$ & $I_{DS}$ & $V_{DS}$ & $R_{DS}$ & P & $P_R$ \\
     \hline\hline
     0 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
     1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
     2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{1000 ohm R selection }
\label{tab: table name}
\end{table}

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that `\begin{table}[]` _means_ that you do not allow the table anywhere. LaTeX assumes you don't really mean that and gives a warning and changes it to `\begin{table}` which means the table is allowed in the default places (usually `[tbp]`)

Comment: So using tbp in the other brackets would solve it?

Comment: The reason that `table`  exists is to allow the table to move to prevent bad page breaks, and be referenced indirectly by its caption. So the most direct fix is not use `[H]` and not use `\FloatBarrier` both of which by design add extra white space tio prevent floats moving, which you then need to fix by hand by re-wording or movig the table

Comment: well as I say using `tbp` will stop the warning but produce the same output (you might prefer `[htbp]` to allow the table to be `here` and not move.

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the original issue, but you might want to take a look at the `siunitx` package in order to improve/unity the numbers and their units. Instead of manually numbered in the "experimental"  and "results"  part, I recommend using an `enumerate` environment. (Can be customized uwing the `enumitem` package.)

Comment: Since some sections/subsections are currently empty, I suggest to firsh finish writing the text that should belongs into these sections before worrying about the table placement at all.

Comment: also do you intend the literal `//` at ends of lines, and why hand positionded `1)` and `2)` not an `enumerate` list?

Comment: as leandris says it is impossible to comment on the float positioning here as there is no real text to fill the pages, also I had to replace your image by `example-image` but that may be a different size so we may be seeing different page breaks and spacing to the pages that you see  with this example.

Answer (score 2):

I adjusted the markup in a few places to arrive at

[image]

Basically you should not worry about the float placement until the text is done and then at the end you could add `\clearpage` if needed before a section heading to flush any floats that are floating too far.

```
% no 12 point option \documentclass[12 point, titlepage]{article}

\documentclass[12pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[hdivide={1in,*,1in}, vdivide={1in,*,1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, longtable, acronym, verbatim, subfigure, tikz, listings, color, float}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\lstdefinestyle{customc}{belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,breaklines=true,frame=L,xleftmargin=\parindent,language=C,showstringspaces=false,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},identifierstyle=\color{blue},stringstyle=\color{orange},}\lstdefinestyle{customasm}{belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,frame=L,xleftmargin=\parindent,language=[x86masm]Assembler,basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
}\lstset{ basicstyle=\scriptsize,numbers=left,numberstyle=\footnotesize,stepnumber=1,numbersep=10pt,backgroundcolor=\color{white},frame=single,captionpos=b,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=false
}


\begin{document}
\author{ Daniel Webb\\
  Electrical Engineering-UNL}
\date{02//2020}
\title{ECEN 347 Lab 2\\
       Date: 3/01/2021 }
\maketitle

\section{Abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Experiment}
\subsection{Transistor Operation Design (Transistor Bias)}
 Design a bias circuit in Fig. for operation in (cutoff, triode, saturation) and note which one has lowest power consumption given $R_1$ =100 ohms, $R_2=1000 ohms$
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{example-image}
    \caption{Mosfet Circuit }
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Place the LED in series with R, 
$V_{DD} = 5\mathrm{V}$ while varying $V_{GS}$ from 0 V to 5 V. Record when the LED starts turning on; this will determine when the transistor is in the on state for overcoming Gate Source voltage required. 
\item Remove the LED and increase $V_{GS}$ observed by 1 V. Step up $V_{DD}$ from 0V : 8V in 1V increments. Measure $I_{DS}$ and $V_{DS}$ for each step value and calculate $R_{DS}$ from these values and Power found by P = power dissipated from transistor ($P_{R_{DS}}$) + drain connected resistor ($P_R$)
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Transistor Inverter, Switching operation}
\subsection{Propogation Delay of Transistor Inverter}
\subsection{Logic Gates}


\section{Results}
\subsection{Transistor Operation Design (Transistor Bias)}
%Summarize the component selection R and operation set up (VGS,VGS(th),VDD,and P) of your design. For each resistor, include VGS(th),VGS and one table with the values of ID,VDS,RDS, P , and PR and for RDS each value of VDD(Numeral 2).


%Operation setup ($V_{GS}$,$V_{GS}$(th),$V_{DD}$,and P) of design }
\subsubsection{Part2: 100 ohm R}

\begin{enumerate}

\item $V_{GS}=$ that turns on LED 

\item Adjusted $V_{GS}= $

\end{enumerate}



\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
     $V_{GS(th)}$& $V_{GS}$ & $V_{DD}$ & $I_{DS}$ & $V_{DS}$ & $R_{DS}$ & P & $P_R$ \\
     \hline\hline
     0 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
     1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
     2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{100 ohm R selection }
\label{tab: table name}
\end{table}

\subsubsection{Part2: 1000 Ohm R}

\begin{enumerate}
 
\item %V_{GS}=$ that turns on LED 

\item Adjusted $V_{GS}= $ 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
     $V_{GS(th)}$& $V_{GS}$ & $V_{DD}$ & $I_{DS}$ & $V_{DS}$ & $R_{DS}$ & P & $P_R$ \\
     \hline\hline
     0 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\  
     1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
     2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     7 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     8 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{1000 ohm R selection }
\label{tab: table namez}
\end{table}

\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I talked with my TA and he arrived a very simple solution by heading [H] as the parameter for the table. basically forces it to be placed "here"

Comment: @DanielWebb I know what `H` does (I implemented it) but it is the wrong thing to do except as a last manual control as a very final edit of the document.